# Where is seconds parameter being passed into method and stored? Converting seconds to string 00:00:00

Tags: ruby, timer, string-formatting, instance-variables, datetime-conversion

I'm getting error:

```
Timer
  should initialize to 0 seconds
  time_string
      should display 0 seconds as 00:00:00 (FAILED - 1)

 Failures:

  1) Timer time_string should display 0 seconds as 00:00:00
     Failure/Error: @timer.seconds = 0
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `seconds=' for #<Timer:0x007fd68b27c8d8>
```

*running following spec*

```
require 'timer'

describe "Timer" do
  before(:each) do
    @timer = Timer.new
  end

 it "should initialize to 0 seconds" do
    @timer.seconds.should == 0
 end

describe 'time_string' do
 it "should display 0 seconds as 00:00:00" do
   @timer.seconds = 0
   @timer.time_string.should == "00:00:00"
end

it "should display 12 seconds as 00:00:12" do
  @timer.seconds = 12
  @timer.time_string.should == "00:00:12"
end
```

*my code:*

```
class Timer

  def timer=(timer  )
    @timer = timer
  end

  def seconds (x = 0)
    @timer = x
  end

  def time_string
   Time.at(@timer).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end
 end
```

I'm getting the first test to initialize to 0 but I don't think i'm doing that right.

Also when I run the code within the time_string method in terminal ruby it returns the correct time. But I just don't know how to send it back when @timer.seconds = 0 or ...seconds = 12 etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `class Timer
 
  def seconds
    @timer = 0
  end
  
  def seconds=
    @timer
  end
  
  def time_string
  @timer = Time.at(@timer).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end


end` Have cleaned it up. yeah I thought my original timer= method set the @timer value. But I was wrong. I've updated per your suggestion. Seemed to get me over the `undefined method `seconds=' for` error. Now it said wrong number of arguments. But the spec doesn't seem to accept arguments.

Comment: got it! updated my code to `def seconds= x
    @timer = x
  end`. Thanks! that was the missing piece. I didn't know you could define a method as seconds=. Thanks!